# Axios Post Request not firing with cancelToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hi I have a progress bar with a cancel button which relate to a file upload. The upload of the file triggers the progress bar. There is a button that cancels the upload process.

As part of cancelling the upload, I am calling two functions. One to create a Axios cancelToken and then the upload file method which contains the token.

The upload file was working up until I added the cancelToken but I still cannot get the cancelling of the file upload to happen at all. Any ideas? I feel I am missing some step with regard to the cancelToken.

Progress Bar:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import LinearProgress from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { Grid, Theme, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import axios, { CancelToken, CancelTokenSource } from "axios";

interface Props {
  value: number;
  fileName: string;
  textStyle?: string;
  fileSize: number;
  textPadding?: string;
  cancelUpload?: () => void;
  // cancelFileUpload?: React.MutableRefObject<null>;
  source?: CancelTokenSource;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  textPadding: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

const LinearProgressWithLabel: React.FC<Props> = ({
  value,
  fileName,
  textStyle,
  fileSize,
  textPadding,
  cancelUpload,
  // cancelFileUpload,
}) => (
  <Grid>
    <Grid className={textPadding}>
      <Typography className={textStyle} variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
        {fileName}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>

    <Grid className={textPadding}>
      <Typography className={textStyle} variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
        {`${(fileSize / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2)}MB`}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
      <Box width="100%" mr={1}>
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={value} />
      </Box>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
      <IconButton onClick={cancelUpload} color="inherit">
        <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
      </IconButton>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
      <Box minWidth={35}>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
          {`${Math.round(value)}%`}
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);

const LinearWithValueLabel: React.FC<Props> = ({
  value,
  fileName,
  fileSize,
  cancelUpload,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) => (prevProgress >= 100 ? 0 : progress));
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LinearProgressWithLabel
        value={value}
        fileName={fileName}
        textPadding={classes.textPadding}
        textStyle={classes.textStyle}
        fileSize={fileSize}
        cancelUpload={cancelUpload}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LinearWithValueLabel;
```

```
let source: CancelTokenSource;
```

Create token:

```
export const deleteFileUploadProgress = async () => await deleteProgress();
```

```
export async function deleteProgress<T>() {
  source = axios.CancelToken.source();
};
```

Upload File:

```
export async function postFiles<T>(
  url: string,
  postForm: FormData,
  queryData: {} = {},
  handleProgress?: (progress: ProgressEvent) => void,
) {
    await axios.post(`${apiRoot}/${url}${objToQuery(queryData)}`, postForm, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      withCredentials: true,
      onUploadProgress: handleProgress,
      cancelToken: source.token,
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(thrown => {
      if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
        console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
      }
    });

  if (true) {
    source.cancel('Request canceled!');
  }
};
```

Comment: please add more details about how you are using these functions and how is reactjs related to this, otherwise remove reactjs tag

Comment: edited with more info

Comment: you didn't add the part where you create the cancel token source, my suspicion is that the source is being replaced with a new one and the cancelation is being done on a different source, could you add the code where you are calling `deleteProgress`?

Comment: I added that line there now. deleteProgress is being called when I click the button but not that I have put the line 'cancelToken: source.token' in the post request, the upload wont start now.

Comment: it's difficult to understand your code, you're just adding unrelated chunks, now I don't know where you are calling `deleteFileUploadProgress`, also I assumed that you are calling the `source.cancel('Request canceled!');` just for testing purpose, right? make sure to write questions in a way people can track the chain of function calls and events

Answer (score 0):

If you put `await` **before** `axios.post(...)`, the client/code will wait for the server response. Hence, the instruction `source.cancel()` will be always executed **after** the request completion.

Comment: Hi I removed the await but its still not calling.

Comment: 1. please, be sure that server responds with a delay (let's say 2000ms);
2. try calling `source.cancel()` in a `setTimeout(cancelFn, 1000)`.